# Alternatives to POSIX semaphores for 64-bit/32-bit IPC?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc, semaphore

I need to implement some sort of blocking wait for a project requiring synchronization between 64-bit and 32-bit processes.  Busy waiting on a shared memory variable introduces performance/scheduling issues and POSIX semaphores do not appear to support IPC between 32-bit and 64-bit processes.  Are there other low-overhead alternatives for interprocess synchronization on Linux?

Comment: You might be able to do something with `std::atomic<uint32_t>`, or something like that. Forget about using anything more complicated than that, like `std::mutex`, since you have no guarantees of that being compatible between 32 and 64 bit code. For simple use cases, simple file locking apporaches might also work.

Comment: I had considered file locking but was concerned about the file I/O overhead.  I was also under the impression that C++11 std::atomic was for communication between *threads* only, not processes.

Comment: Your reference to "shared memory" means that things like `std::atomic` would be an option. As far as file locking goes, it's fairly likely that the chances of actual disk I/O are quite slim, as all operations will be performed in buffered memory. Write a loop to rewrite the same file, containing a few bytes a thousand times. See how much disk activity actually results from that.

Comment: How about traditional pipes or UNIX sockets?

Comment: Since you are on Linux you should consider [Unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). I understand they are slightly faster than pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Linux has [futexes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html) which are a kernel primitive that provides a way for one process to go to sleep and another process to wake it up. They have extremely good fast paths (avoiding kernel calls in those cases) which matters a lot if you use them as a mutex but not so much if you use them as a semaphore.

You would only need its two most primitive functions. One, FUTEX_WAIT, puts a kernel to sleep if, and only if, a particular entry in shared memory has a particular value. The other, FUTEX_WAKE, wakes a process that has gone to sleep with FUTEX_WAIT.

Your "wait" code would atomically check a shared variable to see that it needed to sleep and then call FUTEX_WAIT to go to sleep if, and only if, the shared variable has not changed. Your "wake" code would change the value of the atomic shared variable and then call FUTEX_WAKE to wake any thread that was sleeping.

The 32-bit/64-bit issue would not matter at all if you use a 64-bit shared variable but only put meaningful data in the first 32-bits so it would work the same whether addressed as a 64-bit variable or a 32-bit variable.

Answer (score 0):

For inter-process synchronization using blocking waits, simple solutions include either a [named pipe (fd)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) or a [System V Semaphore](https://dbeck.github.io/system-five-semaphores/).

[Named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) have a file path associated with them, so that the two processes can open the file independently (one for read, the other for write).  For pure synchronization, just `putc()` to signal, and `getc()` to wait, one character at a time (value doesn't matter).  This creates a unidirectional ("half duplex") channel; for bidirectional signal/waits you'd create two files.  You can even queue up multiple signals by performing many `putc()` calls in a row, kind of like a semaphore which never saturates.

[System V Semaphores](https://dbeck.github.io/system-five-semaphores/) also have a file path associated with them.  These behave like a Dijkstra semaphore.

For additional options, check out

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication